# Get daily sales for every day this month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've got a query which gets the total sales figure for the current day

```
SELECT 
    SUM(cso.SubTotal) - (
        SELECT SUM(cso.CreditAvailable) / 1.1 
        FROM dbo.CustomerCredit cso 
        WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cso.DateCreated, 102) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SYSDATETIME(), 102)
    ) AS total_value 
FROM dbo.CustomerInvoice cso 
WHERE
    Convert(VARCHAR(10), cso.InvoiceDate, 102) = Convert(VARCHAR(10), SYSDATETIME(), 102)
```

What I now need, is a table with a list of all the dates in the current month on the left column, and on the right column, the total sales for each date (Using the query above)

```
+---------+---------+
|  date   |  total  |
+---------+---------+
| 1/2/16  | 256232  |
| 2/2/16  | 285632  |
| 3/2/16  | 265231  |
| 4/2/16  | 254215  |
| 5/2/16  |    0    |
| ....... |  .....  |
| 28/2/16 |    0    |
| 29/2/16 |    0    |
+-------------------+
```

It doesn't matter if there are zero sales values for dates which occur in the future or for weekend dates.

I've racked my brains for a solution, but as I'm only new to SQL I decided to reach out to the community.

Comment: I usually use a [Calendar table](http://web.archive.org/web/20150512230546/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html)

Comment: and; of course, 30/2 & 31/2 will never exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use query like this:

```
;with date_cur_month as(
select convert(datetime, convert(varchar(6), getdate(), 112) + '01', 112) as dt
union all
select dateadd(day, 1, dt) as dt
  from date_cur_month
  where datepart(month, dateadd(day, 1, dt)) = datepart(month, getdate()))

select convert(nvarchar(8), d.dt, 3) as date
     , isnull(sum(ci.SubTotal), 0) 
     - isnull((select sum(cc.CreditAvailable) / 1.1 
                 from dbo.CustomerCredit cc
                 where cast(cc.DateCreated as date) = d.dt
              ), 0) as total 
  from dbo.CustomerInvoice ci 
    right outer join date_cur_month d on cast(ci.InvoiceDate as date) = d.dt
  group by d.dt
```

Comment: Thanks!!  That works well... how would I get cumulative sales per day?   So   Sales_Day2 =    (Sales_Day1) + (Sales_Day2)  ??

Comment: For cumulative sales per day you can replace < to <=:
1) cast(ci.InvoiceDate as date) <= d.dt 
2) cast(cc.DateCreated as date) <= d.dt

Comment: You need replace "cast(cc.DateCreated as date) = d.dt" to "cast(cc.DateCreated as date) <= d.dt" and replace "cast(ci.InvoiceDate as date) = d.dt" to "cast(ci.InvoiceDate as date) <= d.dt".

Comment: Thanks! Just a question, how can I get the 'Date' column to display in format  dd/mm/yyyy   ??

Comment: Replace "convert(nvarchar(8), d.dt, 3)" to "convert(nvarchar(10), d.dt, 103)".

Answer (score 0):

First, I believe your query can be written as:

```
SELECT
    SUM(SubTotal) - (SUM(CreditAvailable) / 1.1) AS total
FROM dbo.CustomerInvoice
WHERE CAST(InvoiceDate AS DATE) = CAST(SYSDATETIME() AS DATE)
```

To get the total for each date, just add a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
    SUM(SubTotal) - (SUM(CreditAvailable) / 1.1) AS total
FROM dbo.CustomerInvoice
GROUP BY CAST(InvoiceDate AS DATE)
```

Now, to include all dates, even the dates with 0 total, you have to use a [tally table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/).

```
DECLARE @fromDate AS DATE   = '20160101',
        @toDate AS DATE     = '20160131'

;WITH E1(N) AS(
    SELECT 1 FROM(VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))t(N)
),
E2(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E1 a CROSS JOIN E1 b),
E4(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E2 a CROSS JOIN E2 b), 
CteTally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP(DATEDIFF(DAY, @fromDate, @toDate) + 1) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL))
    FROM E4
),
CteDates(dt) AS(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, N - 1, @fromDate) FROM CteTally
)
SELECT
    d.dt, t.total
FROM CteDates d
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        dt = CAST(InvoiceDate AS DATE),
        total = SUM(SubTotal) - (SUM(CreditAvailable) / 1.1)
    FROM dbo.CustomerInvoice
    WHERE InvoiceDate >= @fromDate AND InvoiceDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @toDate)
    GROUP BY CAST(InvoiceDate AS DATE)
) t
    ON t.dt = d.dt
```

Comment: Thanks Felix! I think this will work, except that you missed the fact that  'CreditAvailable'   is on the table   dbo.CustomerCredit.    All the rest are on    dbo.CustomerInvoice.  I've reformatted to show                dt = CAST(InvoiceDate AS DATE), SUM(SubTotal) - (SELECT SUM(CreditAvailable) / 1.1 FROM dbo.CustomerCredit WHERE DateCreated >= @fromDate AND DateCreated < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @toDate)) AS total

Comment: Completely missed that part. Anyway, you can edit this answer.

Comment: This isn't giving me the right numbers at all Felix... :(

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cteRange
AS (SELECT
        DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS Start_Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        DATEADD(DAY, 1, cteRange.Start_Date)
    FROM cteRange
    WHERE cteRange.Start_Date < DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0))
    )
SELECT
    cteRange.Start_Date, ISNULL(inv.SubTotal,0), ISNULL(crd.CredAvail,0)
  , ISNULL(inv.SubTotal,0) - ISNULL(crd.CredAvail / 1.1,0) AS total
FROM cteRange
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
            CAST(cc.DateCreated AS date) AS DateCreated
          , SUM(cc.CreditAvailable) AS CredAvail
        FROM dbo.CustomerCredit AS cc
        WHERE cc.DateCreated >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
        GROUP BY CAST(cc.DateCreated AS date)
        ) AS crd ON cteRange.Start_Date = crd.DateCreated
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
            CAST(cso.InvoiceDate AS date) AS InvoiceDate
          , SUM(cso.SubTotal) As SubTotal
        FROM dbo.CustomerInvoice AS cso
        WHERE cso.InvoiceDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
        GROUP BY CAST(cso.InvoiceDate AS date)
        ) AS inv ON cteRange.Start_Date = inv.InvoiceDate
;
```

This calculation returns the first day of the current month: `DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)`  then  "recursive common table expression" (CTE) adds one day to that date for all valid days in the current month. So we end up with a set of rows for the month. Then we use left joins to your financial data.

For each of the 2 tables involved we summarize any data in the current month by day which permits the join to occur.

Please note that for best performance from date/time information you should try to avoid converting these into varchars.

Comment: Thanks, just getting an error for 'Incorrect syntax near AS'    after   "GROUP BY CAST(cc.DateCreated AS date)"   ??

Comment: apologies, I had one too many closing parenthesis in an ISNULL() reference, there is now a new line commencing `, ISNULL(` the correction is within the second part of that calculation `ISNULL(crd.CredAvail / 1.1,0) AS total` which was incorrectly `ISNULL(crd.CredAvail / 1.1),0)` *[that parenthesis after 1.1 was wrong]*

Comment: by the way this isn't setup for cumulative values, that wasn't clear from the question

Comment: Thanks... any way we can hide the middle 2 columns? I really only need the calculation of the total...

Comment: Sure, just remove them from the select clause. If you dont try it you won't learn.  Nb. Commas separate the columns listed in the select clause. It is the select clause that has isnull references you need to change